# Python List of Strings to Tuple Pairs

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am having some difficulty coming up with an efficient way of taking a list of strings and converting it to tuple pairs.  I have a list similar to:

```
listOfNames = ['red-l','blue-l','green-s','red-s','blue-s']
```

Every color in this example (red, blue, and green) has either a '-l' or '-s' entry or both.  I need to convert this list of strings into tuple pairs such as:

```
tupleOfNames = [('red-l','red-s'),(None,'green-s'),('blue-l','blue-s')]
```

I think regular expressions is needed but I am not sure how to do so.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: how long is the list

Comment: The list should never be more than ~10 thousand entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a nice (and perhaps better) solution is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
listOfNames = ['red-l','blue-l','green-s','red-s','blue-s']
# Go over the list and remember for each color the entry 
for s in listOfNames:
   d[s[:-2]].append(s[-1])
# Go over the colors and produce the appropriate tuple
[ (key+'-l' if 'l' in d[key] else None, key+'-s' if 's' in d[key] else None) for key in d.keys() ]
```

That outputs:

```
[('blue-l', 'blue-s'), ('red-l', 'red-s'), (None, 'green-s')]
```

With that method you go just one time over the original list and one time over the color keys (which is smaller).

The access to the dictionary is `O(1)` on average so thats should work fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, We can sort the list firstly and then groupby the color part of each term and transform each group into a tuple, if it contains only one element insert a None in the tuple:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

li = []
listOfNames.sort()
for k, g in groupby(listOfNames, lambda s: re.findall("(.*)-", s)):
    liG = list(g)
    if len(liG) == 1:
        li.append((None, liG[0]))
    else:
        li.append(tuple(liG))

li
# [('blue-l', 'blue-s'), (None, 'green-s'), ('red-l', 'red-s')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function which is far from perfect, but delivers the result you wish for:

```
  def tupleofnames(listofnames):
        result = []
        colors = set([x[:-2] for x in listOfNames])    
        for c in colors:         
            if c+"-l" in listofnames:
                if c+'-s' in listofnames:
                    result.append((c+"-l",c+'-s'))
                else: 
                    result.append((c+"-l",None))
            else:
                result.append((None,c+"-s"))
        return result
```

Result looks like:

```
[(None, 'green-s'), ('red-l', 'red-s'), ('blue-l', 'blue-s')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfNames = ['red-l','blue-l','green-s','red-s','blue-s']
l_list = [a[:-2] for a in filter(lambda x:x[-1]=='l',listOfNames)]
s_list = [a[:-2] for a in filter(lambda x:x[-1]=='s',listOfNames)]
s = {a[:-2] for a in listOfNames}
tuplesOfNames = [tuple([c+'-l' if c in l_list else None,c+'-s' if c in s_list else None]) for c in s]
```

Output:

```
[('blue-l', 'blue-s'), ('red-l', 'red-s'), (None, 'green-s')]
```

This will be slightly faster than alternatives due to spliting into 2 separate lists for elements, so that lookup is bit faster.

Answer (score -3):

Check out the `itertools.product()` function. This returns the cartesian product of two lists. In your case you could do,

```
from itertools import product

l_names = ['red-l', 'blue-l']
s_names = ['red-s', 'blue-s', 'green-s']

tupleOfNames = list(product(l_names, s_names))
```

Comment: but this assumes the OP has two or more lists. What if (like in the question) there is only one list of many different strings

Comment: This is a simple solution based on the OP's provided use case example. I'll leave it to the OP to decide whether he needs a more flexible approach.

Comment: OP doesn't need cartesian product. Look at sample output. You give 6 tuples, sample is 3.

Comment: It looks to me like he just didn't want to write all of the possible tuples out.

Comment: No, I do not need a cartesian product of all the values.  Thank you for your answer, though.